# Missing dependency (transitive "implementation" type) when using trait

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm getting an error when compiling a module that uses a trait defined in another module due to a missing dependency. The project is built with Gradle and its structure is the following:

- `:lib`

  - Defines the `HelperFromLibrary` trait, which has a private field of type `Appender`(from log4j).
  - Log4j is added as an `implementation` dependency.
- `:host`

  - `:lib` is added as an `implementation` dependency.
  - Defines a `Host` class which implements the `HelperFromLibrary` trait.

The project can be found in this repo: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/gradle-groovy-trait.

When compiling the host with `./gradlew :host:compileGroovy` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class gradledeps.lib.HelperFromLibrary$Trait$FieldHelper due to missing dependency Lorg/apache/log4j/Appender;
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.Java8.configureClassNode(Java8.java:460)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1019)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1005)
    at org.apache.groovy.ast.tools.ClassNodeUtils.getDeclaredMethodsFromSuper(ClassNodeUtils.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getDeclaredMethodsMap(ClassNode.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getAllDeclaredMethods(ClassNode.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.trait.TraitComposer.applyTrait(TraitComposer.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.trait.TraitComposer.doExtendTraits(TraitComposer.java:109)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$addPhaseOperations$6(CompilationUnit.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$IPrimaryClassNodeOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:942)
```

This seems to be related to how Groovy applies the trait on consumers, which seems to require log4j to be available in the *compile* classpath due to the field in the trait. Since log4j is an `implementation` dependency I wasn't expecting that.

Is this by design? A bug? Am I missing something?

Are there any workarounds for this? I'd prefer not making the log4j dependency in `:lib` an `api` dependency, which would make it available to consumer's compile classpath. Also, adding log4j as a `compileOnly` dependency in `:host` is really weird.

Note that the example project is a bit simplified; in the real scenario adding the `api` dependency would feel like a smell.

Comment: Does the code compile for you if you make a change like the one described at https://github.com/jeffbrown/gradle-groovy-trait/commit/59ded63f63236a572a58549cf7c69e6a73be9d4e?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes, it does, because then log4j ends up in the host's compile classpath. But that's what I'd like to avoid...

Comment: "because then log4j ends up in the host's compile classpath" - Are you anticipating that `log4j` will be on your runtime classpath?

Comment: Yes.  Since it is declared as an "implementation" dependency, Gradle will make it available to the host project's runtime. Running `./gradlew :host:dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency log4j` confirms this.

Comment: It isn't clear to me how what you are asking for is even possible.  I am sorry that I can't help.